# Arrange DIV in circle and rotate them facing outwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I've managed to layout my DIV elements into a circle shape but I've not managed to work out how to calculate the deg of rotation need to have them face OUTWARD from the center of the circle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('test_box');

                var increase = Math.PI * 2 / elems.length;
                var x = 0, y = 0, angle = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    var elem = elems[i];
                    // modify to change the radius and position of a circle
                    x = 400 * Math.cos(angle) + 700;
                    y = 400 * Math.sin(angle) + 700;
                    elem.style.position = 'absolute';
                    elem.style.left = x + 'px';
                    elem.style.top = y + 'px';
                    //need to work this part out
                    var rot = 45;
                    elem.style['-moz-transform'] = "rotate("+rot+"deg)";
                    elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+rot+"deg)";
                    elem.style['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate("+rot+"deg)";
                    elem.style['-o-transform'] = "rotate("+rot+"deg)";
                    elem.style['-ms-transform'] = "rotate("+rot+"deg)";
                    angle += increase;
                    console.log(angle);
                }
            });
```

does anyone have to knowledge on how I can do this.

Cheers -C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `rot` depends on `angle`, except `angle` is in radians.

DRY, so either convert from angle to rot:

```
// The -90 (degrees) makes the text face outwards.
var rot = angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
```

Or just use angle when setting the style (but use radians as a unit), and drop `rot`'s declaration:

```
// The -0.5*Math.PI (radians) makes the text face outwards.
elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+(angle-0.5*Math.PI)+"rad)";
```

Comment: Brilliant, I really need to learn a thing out two about angles, and radians etc... useful knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var rot = 90 + (i * (360 / elems.length));
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gWZdd/

I've added the 90 degrees at the start there to ensure the baseline of the divs face towards the centre, however you can adjust this to suit your needs.